# Convert GridView Matter to image file like .jpeg

Tags: android, listview, gridview

It is not long time to for me to command on Android.
But From The help I learn Much. Thx to StackOverflow community.
Now I question getting hard for me!
Please help me.
As above subject I want to create jpeg file from GridView.
here is my code of gridview only.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridView lv1 = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
    List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,li);
    lv1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("/sdcard/ctron/sales.db", null);
        Cursor cr = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM g001", null);
        if (cr != null) {
            if (cr.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String accode = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("accode"));
                    String desc = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("desc"));
                    String place = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("place"));
                    li.add(accode);
                    li.add(desc);
                    li.add(place);
                    lv1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                } while (cr.moveToNext());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Problem in Database!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

}

Please help me how to Create image

Answer (score 0):

This code will create a `Bitmap` given a `View`

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

To save it to a jpeg file, you then use `Bitmap.compress`:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outputStream);
```

Comment: sorry but can you please say me in details

Comment: and what is "outputstrem"

Comment: is it path of file name or any other

Comment: Its a file or any other stream. Read about it here maybe http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html